# How to write JUnit test for a method that calls API?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I've to write test for a class that calls an API and then processes the response. The class has two public functions and a private function. The first public method fetches a list of IDs. The second public method is called in a loop for every ID to get details associated with an ID. The private method is called inside the second public method, since the calls to fetch details based on id are made asynchronously.

I'm new to JUnits and while I understand that I should not test the API calls, just my functions, I still don't understand what should the unit tests assert.

Below are my functions:

```
public List<Integer> fetchVehicleIds(String datasetId) throws ApiException {

    VehiclesApi vehiclesApi = new VehiclesApi();

    List<Integer> vehicleIds;
    vehicleIds = vehiclesApi.vehiclesGetIds(datasetId).getVehicleIds();

    return vehicleIds;
}

 public List<VehicleResponse> fetchVehicleDetails(String datasetId, List<Integer> vehicleIds) throws InterruptedException, ApiException {

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(vehicleIds.size());
    List<VehicleResponse> vehiclesList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Integer vehicleId: vehicleIds) {
        populateEachVehicleDetail(datasetId, vehicleId, vehiclesList, latch);
    }

    latch.await();

    return vehiclesList;
}

private void populateEachVehicleDetail(String datasetId, Integer vehicleId, List<VehicleResponse> vehiclesList, CountDownLatch latch) throws ApiException {

    ApiCallback<VehicleResponse> vehicleResponseApiCallback = new ApiCallback<VehicleResponse>() {
        @Override
        synchronized public void onSuccess(VehicleResponse result, int statusCode, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) {
            vehiclesList.add(result);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    };

    VehiclesApi vehiclesApi = new VehiclesApi();
    vehiclesApi.vehiclesGetVehicleAsync(datasetId,vehicleId,vehicleResponseApiCallback);

}
```

Based on the research I've done so far, I think I have to mock the API calls using mockito? I'm still unclear on how the functionality can be unit tested.

Comment: Basically, you want to isolate this class from an actual API by making everything it interacts with a Mock you control. So create a Mock VehiclesAPI, inject it (through a setter that's not here) and handle all calls to it with mocked responses of your own making.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two statements are indeed the things that you want to isolate in your unit test:

```
private void populateEachVehicleDetail(String datasetId, Integer vehicleId, List<VehicleResponse> vehiclesList, CountDownLatch latch) throws ApiException {
....
    VehiclesApi vehiclesApi = new VehiclesApi();
    vehiclesApi.vehiclesGetVehicleAsync(datasetId,vehicleId,vehicleResponseApiCallback);
...
}
```

1) Make you dependency mockable

But you can mock only something that you can set from the client side of the class.
Here the API is a local variable. So you should change your class to expose the dependency, for example in the constructor.
In this way you could mock it easily.

2) Make your mock not return a result but invoke the callback.

In a synchronous invocation context, you want to mock a returned result.
In an asynchronous invocation context with a callback, things are different. Indeed callbacks don't return to the caller but callbacks are invoked to provide the result of the invocation.So here what you want is that the mocked API invokes the `onSuccess()` callback with mocked parameters that represent the data set for your unit test :

```
@Override
synchronized public void onSuccess(VehicleResponse result, int statusCode, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) {
    vehiclesList.add(result);
    latch.countDown();
}
```

In your unit test you should mock in this way the callback for each expected invocation :

```
@Mock
VehiclesApi vehiclesApiMock;
// ...

// when the api method is invoked with the expected dataSetId and vehicleId
Mockito.when(vehiclesApiMock.vehiclesGetVehicleAsync(Mockito.eq(datasetId), Mockito.eq(vehicleId),
                                                 Mockito.any(ApiCallback.class)))
       // I want to invoke the callback with the mocked data
       .then(invocationOnMock -> {
           ApiCallback<VehicleResponse> callback = invocationOnMock.getArgument(2);
           callback.onSuccess(mockedVehicleResponse, mockedStatusCode,
                              mockedResponseHeaders);
           return null; // it is a void method. So no value to return in T then(...).
       });
```

I think that a cast is missing for `ApiCallback` but you should have the overall idea.

Answer (score 3):

You are right: since you want to test your unit (i.e. the presented code), you should mock the API (mainly: the `vehicleApi` instance).

As-is right now, there is no way to inject a mocked instance of `VehicleApi` in your code (well, there is, but it would involve use of reflection... let's not go down this road). You can apply [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) to make your code testable: instead of constructing a `VehicleApi` within your object, write a constructor that expects a `VehicleApi`-instance:

```
public class YourClass {
    private final VehicleApi vehicleApi;

    public YourClass(final VehicleApi vehicleApi) {
        this.vehicleApi = vehicleApi;
    }

    [...]
}
```

What have you won? Well, now you can inject a mocked object into your unit under test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJRunner.class)
public class YourClassTest {

    private final VehicleApi vehicleApiMock = mock(VehicleApi.class);
    private final YourClass underTest = new YourClass(vehicleApiMock);

    @Test
    void someTest() {
        // GIVEN
        [wire up your mock if necessary]

        // WHEN
        [write the test-call]

        // THEN
        [verify that the unit under test is in the expected state]
    }
}
```

This example assumes JUnit5 as testing- and Mockito as mocking-framework, but there are other options as well.

The test is written in [Gherkin language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software)#Gherkin_language):
- the `GIVEN` block describes the preconditions, i.e. in which the unit under test and the external (mocked) system(s) are in
- the `WHEN` block executes the action that should be tested
- the `THEN` block validates that the unit under test is in the expected state.